# Shell script - Find files modified today, create directory, and move them there

Tags: linux, bash, shell, filesystems

I was wondering if there is a simple and concise way of writing a shell script that would go through a series of directories, (*i.e.*, one for each student in a class), determine if within that directory there are any files that were modified within the last day, and only in that case the script would create a subdirectory and copy the files there. So if the directory had no files modified in the last 24h, it would remain untouched. My initial thought was this:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /path/people/ #this directory has multiple subdirectories

for i in `ls`
do
   if find ./$i -mtime -1  -type f  then 
     mkdir ./$i/updated_files
     #code to copy the files to the newly created directory
   fi
done
```

However, that seems to create /updated_files for all subdirectories, not just the ones that have recently modified files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Heavier use of `find` will probably make your job much easier. Something like

```
find /path/people -mtime -1 -type f -printf "mkdir --parents %h/updated_files\n" | sort | uniq | sh
```

Comment: Thanks. This statement works fine for creating the subfolders :) How would I incorporate a statement that copies multiple recently modified files into the folder just created? Does **find** give me a flag holding the list of files found?

Comment: @Everaldo Aguiar: Can you post the solution here, please?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are assuming the **find** command will fail if it finds nothing.  The exit code is zero (success) even if it finds nothing that matches.

Something like

```
UPDATEDFILES=`find ./$i -mtime -1  -type f`
[ -z "$UPDATEDFILES" ] && continue
mkdir ...
cp ...
...
```